# Need to find principal-id in xml with python

Tags: python, xml, urllib2

Using urllib2.Request(url) and BeautifulSoup returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
 <status code="ok">
 </status>
 <principal-list>
  <principal account-id="1013353221" has-children="false" is-hidden="false" is-primary="false" principal-id="1013353225" training-group-id="" type="user">
   <name>
    First Last
   </name>
   <login>
    first.last
   </login>
   <email>
    first.last@domain.com
   </email>
   <display-uid>
    first.last
   </display-uid>
  </principal>
  <principal account-id="1013353221" has-children="false" is-hidden="false" is-primary="false" principal-id="1115269931" training-group-id="" type="user">
   <name>
    First Last
   </name>
   <login>
    first.last
   </login>
   <email>
    first.last@domain.com
   </email>
   <display-uid>
    first.last
   </display-uid>
  </principal>
 </principal-list>
</results>
```

This is what I'm doing to return the list you see above:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
userlist = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(userlist)
print(soup.prettify())
```

I'd like toe call `username = sys.argv[1]` and have it return the `principal-id` for the `username` contained in `<login> </login>`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try looking into [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which parses html.

Comment: WOW! Why didn't I think of that. It looks so much nicer now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I have a much better question now.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...sounds interesting.

Try something like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
userlist = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(userlist)

username = sys.argv[1]

def get_id(username_var):
    tags = soup.findAll('login')
    for data in tags:
        if str(data.contents[0]).strip() != username_var:
            continue
        print data.parent['account-id']

get_id(username)
```

This should return the account ID associated with the username provided.

Comment: if this worked for you, then you should click the check icon next to this entry.